# IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0 while filling dataset

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, exception, dataset

when i want to run this code I get an error which throws "IndexOutOfRangeException" on for loop condition. I have tried to use breakpoints and after my DataSet populated clicked on magnifying glass on it. The Visualizer says that it was an empty DataSet. I would appreciate it if someone can help me!

My PageLoad function includes `if(!IsPostBack)` like this: `(freeQuery.aspx.cs)`

```
if (!IsPostBack
{
    ViewState["sortColumn"] = " ";
    ViewState["sortDirection"] = " ";

    string pageURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
    DataSet tables = new DataSet();
    string queryString2 = "show tables;";
    tables = connectHive(queryString2, pageURL);
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tables.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        list.Add(tables.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
    }
    ListBox1.DataSource = list;
    ListBox1.DataBind();
    ListBox1.Rows = (ListBox1.Items.Count / 2) + 3;
}
```

and `connectHive` function in `BasePage.cs` below:

```
protected DataSet connectHive(string query, string pageURL)
{ // Hadoop Hive Connection
    var page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
    OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Hive2");
    DbConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 20000000;
    try
    {
        DbConnection.Open();
    }
    catch (OdbcException exep)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Error in Query!');window.location ='" + pageURL.Replace("/", "") + "';", true);
    }

    OdbcCommand cmd = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
    OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, DbConnection);
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 20000000;
    DataSet data = new DataSet();
    data.EnforceConstraints = false;
    try
    {
        adapter.Fill(data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        List<string> parameters = new List<string>();
        string pageName = findNameByUrl(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        parameters.Add("UserID:");
        parameters.Add(Session["sicil"].ToString());
        parameters.Add("Exception:");
        parameters.Add(ex.ToString());
        string parameterString = castParameters(parameters);
        string exception = "";
        string[] sep = new string[] { "\r\n" };
        string[] lines = ex.ToString().Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int position = lines[0].ToString().LastIndexOf("FAILED:");
        if (position > -1)
        exception = lines[0].ToString().Substring(position, lines[0].Length - position);
        Session["Exception"] = exception.Replace("'", "");
        Log(query, "Select Table(BasePage)", pageName, "Failed", parameterString);
    }

    DbConnection.Close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: What's the query actually being run? I suspect that it's just returning the one set, not a collection of tables, hence the error. What's the `Count` property value?

Comment: Can you ensure that `DbConnection.Open();` is not throwing an exception?

Comment: Please make sure that the query is returning data and also always perform null and count check before proceeding with loop or any kind of operations on objects and collections.

Comment: There is an error in your query.

Comment: When i debug both IsPostBack and connectHive func together, getting an error like this on `catch{ ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript....bla bla  }` line : _ "OdbcExceptionWasCaught ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified" _  I have researched a bit and learned that User/System DSN settings inside Administrative Tools -> Data Sources(ODBC) should have been set. Please help me to get rid of these confusing things @Ferus7 it says `Count` is 0 @DiskJunky @Hari Govind

Comment: `OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Hive2   UID=User;  PWD=Password;");` Try no set an user and password to connect your DB, it seems like you dont have permissions

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me :( @Ferus7

Comment: are you using a valid user/password?, does the datasource `Hive2` exist? This is the point your application is breaking up. we must ensure to make the connection to work, are yo using oracle or sql server?

Comment: You're right, permission is denied from my localhost. And for now there is nothing to do till the deployment. Thanks for your help, it means a lot to me! @Ferus7

Comment: I'm glad I can help you ^^